# Can an Electron JS App on MS WIndows in the system tray listen for keyboard events and launch popup windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

I need to build a program that can run on MIcrosoft WIndows which will be a system tray app.  It needs to sit running in the tray and listen for keyboard presses.  When a mapped key is pressed it will need to open a popup panel which will list and show software shortcuts which when clicked will open the selected software and close the popup window.

It is basically an app launcher which will show a list of software dependent on which keyboard key mapping was triggered.  For example keyboard mapping 1 would show software shortcuts in the popup window that are added to an `Image editing` category.  Another key would open the same window but show software shortcuts for `text editing` and so on.

As I am a web developer (PHP and JavaScript).  Building a true Windows C++ or C# style app is out of my abilities!

This is where the software called **Electron** which allows to build cross platform desktop apps using web languages (JS, HTML, CSS) might be able to build what I need and allow me to do it myself!

Electron - http://electron.atom.io/

So the Electron app would need to:

- Sit in tray and listen for key presses
- When a mapped key is detected it would need to open a popup window with the category of software items associated with that key
- When software in the popup is clicked on, it needs to open that software and close the popup window.
- When no software is clicked on and a click hapens anywhere else on the screen it needs to close that popup window.

It would then also need a basic settings panel window to

- assign keyboard shortcuts to categories
- add/delete software shortcuts storing the **software name**, **file path**, **category**, and optional **icon or image**

---

**Question**

My real question now is.  Can an Electron app that is running in the windows task tray listen for keys and also able to open and close the popup windows?

---

Below is an image to show how basic the popup windows need to be.  It is just a matter of being capable of opening a popup window from the tray app without a main window ap being opened or focused

[image]

---

### UPDATE

I have confirmed that an Electron app in the system tray can listen for keyboard events and launch windows when they happen using [globalShortcut](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/global-shortcut/).

**globalShortcut** http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/global-shortcut/

> Detect keyboard events when the application does not have keyboard
>   focus.

I am not sure yet about:

- opening other program shortcuts from my app
- closing the popup on selection of item or window losing focus

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use globalShortcut for that. But globalShortcuts emits the keypress event on OS so if you set shortcut to CTRL+C, It will be executed on your app and will not 'copy' as default. Just keep that in mind and choose your shortcut carefully.

Secondly, I don't know if there's an exact way to do this but you can run any command line command on nodejs so you can run the exe of any app on electron using [childProcess.execSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options).

You can create a BrowserWindow any time you want and specify their location and sizes. And listen to their [events](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#instance-events) to close them when they lost their focus.

Comment: Is there any way to use CTRL + C for copy as well as an event??  Like this app https://clipto.pro/#/